# Create a file (.txt) in a specific spot on the desktop by using the command line

Tags: cmd.exe

I know I can create a .txt file on the desktop by using

```
copy nul > file.txt
```

but I want to create it on a specific spot on the desktop. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: by "specific spot", you mean positioning the icon in a specific corner of the screen or something? (the desktop is already a specific folder for that user)

Answer (score 0):

Add a path to the output side of the >

```
copy nul > C:\Users\Profile\Desktop\Folder\file.txt
```

If there are spaces put quotes around the destination.

Comment: I think you got me wrong. :D I want to create it for example in the middle of the desktop.

Comment: Oh like a specific X/Y layout spot?

Answer (score 0):

[This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028737/programatic-desktop-icon-placement#1028756) is probably what you need. It talks about programmatically changing the position of icons on the desktop.

Unfortunately it sounds complicated. You probably won't be able to do it with a simple command like you're starting with.